# How to assign a property in php?

Tags: php, properties

I have given an `<a>` element a `data-filter` property, as shown:

```
<ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="all current"><?php _e('All', 'framework'); ?></a>
        <span>/</span>
    </li> 

    <?php  
    wp_list_categories(array( 
            'title_li' => '',  
            'taxonomy' =>  
            'skill-type',  
            'walker' => new Portfolio_Walker(), 
            'show_option_none' => '' 
        ) 
    );
    ?> 
</ul>
```

How can I pass this `data-filter` property to PHP?

Comment: Your answer is not too clear. Please try again. I can't undertaint what you mean with "assign property to PHP" ?

Comment: Do you mean pass it when you click the link?

Comment: If that is what I understaint.  the Portfolio_Walker is the function that generate your list. In that function foreach anchor you create <a href="#" .... you can add also the property data-filter="*" and then will appearing on each link

Comment: @MerianosNikos Sorry! I want to give to `wp_list_categories` (in PHP) a `data-filter` property.

Comment: You are not able to pass extra options to that function.

Comment: @Merianos Nikos: Thank you Merianos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass this data-filter property to PHP?

You can't. It's not possible using pure HTML and PHP to transfer a certain (made-up) HTML attribute to PHP. A decent alternative is to use a form instead, where you could select a radio button and submit the form.

**EDIT**:

Another alternative is to simply pass the filter through the request's query string:

```
<li>
    <a href="?data-filter=*" class="all current"><?php _e('All', 'framework'); ?></a>
    <span>/</span>
</li> 

// in PHP:
$data_filter = $_GET['data-filter'];
echo $data_filter;
```